# Primefaces selectOneMenu update outputLabel and inputText

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, selectonemenu

I've googled and stackoverflowed a lot but I can't seem to find the answer.
What needs to be done is that the outputLabel's value needs to be updated when the selection change, also inputText's disabled needs to change to enabled when you select option B. (Furthermore; the selected value is displayed in the inputText)

My xhtml snipped:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="findex" value="#{myController.selected.findex}" >
    <p:ajax update="extra1 labelextra1" immediate="true"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Value A" itemValue="A" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Value B" itemValue="B" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:outputLabel id="labelextra1" value="#{myController.selected.findex == 'A' ? '' : 'X'}" for="extra1"/>
<p:inputText id="extra1" value="#{myController.selected.findex}" disabled="#{myController.selected.findex == 'A'}"/>
```

(A listener in my backing bean does get called if I add it to the ajax, but I'm not sure that I require that, it is a simple on change event, isn't it?)

Comment: Does it work without `immediate="true"`?

Comment: Nope, no change with or without immediate="true"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make a little example. This works fine. I think you have no `<h:form>` right? You need a form for it.

**.XHTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<title>Jsf page.</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="findex" value="#{myController.test}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Value A" itemValue="A" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Value B" itemValue="B" />
        <p:ajax update="labelextra1 extra1" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>

    <p:outputLabel id="labelextra1" value="#{myController.test}" for="extra1" />
    <p:inputText id="extra1" value="hello" disabled="#{myController.test == 'A'}"/>
</h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

**BEAN:**

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyController implements Serializable{

private String test = "hallo";


public String getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(String test) {
    this.test = test;
}


}
```

Comment: It is in a    <h:form>  This example does work, and I've incorporate it in the actual xhtml.  It works until I start to use my db entity which the form is based on.  The solution is more complex but I got to get it to work. The     disabled logic is in the controller (not in the xhtml)